# Proving $f(T_1 \oplus T_2) = f(T_1) \oplus f(T_2)$ for $T = T_1 \oplus T_2$

Tags: linear-transformations, direct-sum

I'm trying to prove that, for every field $F$, vector space $V$ over $F$, and linear mapping $T: V \to V$,
if $T = T_1 \oplus T_2$, then
$$
f(T_1 \oplus T_2) = f(T_1) \oplus f(T_2)
$$

Going from RHS, each of the components must be independent, but I can't connect it to LHS.

Comment: This question will be much easier to answer if you explain the meanings of your symbols. What are the $T_i$ and $V$? What is $F$?

Comment: I've added the information.

Comment: How do you define $T_1\oplus T_2$?  Usually, one would also have $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ and $T_1:V_1\rightarrow V_1$ and $T_2:V_2\rightarrow V_2$.  However, there are other options ...

Comment: Exactly as you've noted. It's just a shortcut. $T_1 \oplus T_2$ is used by my current lecturer, I thought it's a well defined notation.

Comment: Yes, it's well-defined notation, but you never defined $T_1$ or $T_2$ in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $T_i:V_i\rightarrow V_i$ are linear transformations for $i=1,2$ and $T_i^k$ means the composition of $T_i$ with itself $k$ times.  Moreover, $V=V_1\oplus V_2$.  I understand $T_1\oplus T_2$ to be $T_1\oplus T_2:V\rightarrow V$.  In other words, $(v_1,v_2)\mapsto (T_1(v_1),T_2(v_2))$.  Let $f=\sum a_ix^i$.  Then, 
\begin{align*}
f(T_1\oplus T_2)(v_1,v_2)&=\left(\sum a_i (T_1\oplus T_2)^i\right)(v_1,v_2)\\
&=\sum a_i(T_1\oplus T_2)^i(v_1,v_2)\\
&=\sum a_i\left(T_1^i(v_1),T_2^i(v_2))\right)\\
&=\sum \left(a_iT_1^i(v_1),a_iT_2^i(v_2))\right)\\
&=\left(\sum a_iT_1^i(v_1),\sum a_iT_2^i(v_2))\right)\\
&=\left(f(T_1)(v_1),f(T_2)(v_2)\right)\\
&=(f(T_1)\oplus f(T_2))(v_1,v_2).
\end{align*}